# How to read directory names containing Khmer script (non Windows native encoding) with list.files() in R?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a set of directories with English and Khmer names, containing images. I want to use R produce a list of all files and folders. When I use base R functions to list images and directories, directories with Khmer characters in the folder name (and the images they contain) are ignored and don't appear in the output.

**Example directory and image files**

```
FolderA
FolderA/Image1.JPG
FolderB_ឆ្កែ
FolderB_ឆ្កែ/Image2.JPG
FolderC
```

**What happens**

```
# define image directory
TargetDirectory <- "D:/ExampleDir" # define image directory

# find all image filenames
filenames_full <- list.files(TargetDirectory, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE,
                             pattern = ".JPG$") # Get all the image filenames and paths
filenames_full

> "FolderA/Image1.JPG"

dirs <- list.dirs(TargetDirectory) # Get all the folders (including empty)
dirs 

> "FolderA" "FolderC"
```

This correctly returns `FolderA/Image1.JPG` in `list.files()` and correctly returns `FolderA` and `FolderC` in `list.dirs()`, but misses `FolderB_ឆ្កែ/Image2.JPG` and `FolderB_ឆ្កែ` from these outputs, apparently failing because of the Khmer script in the name of `FolderB_ឆ្កែ`

The help documentation for `list.files()` states: "Elements with a marked encoding will be converted to the native encoding (and if that fails, considered non-existent)", and there is discussion online about the Windows version of R not handling encoding as expected in some cases, as Windows is not natively UTF-8. There is a dev version of R that appears to be intended to address these types of issues (https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/index.html). However, when trying to load RStudio using this version, I get a "This site cannot be loaded" error. Before going too far down troubleshooting this last error and messing around with legacy versions of RStudio etc, I wanted to explore other options and confirm I'm on the right track.

What approaches in R could be used to result in a list of files and directories, including the ones with Khmer script? If there is no solution, I may use PowerShell to produce the lists then read into R, but I would prefer to try an R based approach first.

Comment: For windows you need to install language package and set it as active language for running - This is problem with windows not with `r` or programming issue.

May you reference to this post in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with the Khmer language pack installed, Khmer set as the "Default app language" and the "Windows display language", the "Region" as Cambodia, and the "Regional format" as Cambodia, the problem persists and the output is the same as described in my original post, so I'm not sure this is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference on a Linux system - Here is a sample demonstrate the problem is with Windows system not with R. I am working on to get the languague pack and it usually fix but I don't think this question should be asked here. It should be in superuser forum instead.

[image]

```r
Sys.info()
#>                                       sysname 
#>                                       "Linux" 
#>                                       release 
#>                           "5.10.36-2-MANJARO" 
#>                                       version 
#> "#1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 11 19:38:44 UTC 2021" 
#>                                      nodename 
#>                               "sinh-Thinkpad" 
#>                                       machine 
#>                                      "x86_64" 
#>                                         login 
#>                                        "sinh" 
#>                                          user 
#>                                        "sinh" 
#>                                effective_user 
#>                                        "sinh"

list.files(path = "Sample", recursive = "TRUE")
#> [1] "Folder_C/2020-09-19_18-14.png"      "FolderA/2020-09-19_18-14.png"      
#> [3] "FolderB_ឆ្កែ/2020-09-19_18-14_2.png" "FolderB_ឆ្កែ/2020-09-19_18-14.png"

list.dirs(path = "Sample")
#> [1] "Sample"             "Sample/Folder_C"    "Sample/FolderA"    
#> [4] "Sample/FolderB_ឆ្កែ"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

On the other hand, with a Virtual PC running Windows without setting the language pack, when access the same folder I got the problem you mentioned.

```r
Sys.info()
#>           sysname           release           version          nodename 
#>         "Windows"          "10 x64"     "build 19042" "DESKTOP-F9R7U11" 
#>           machine             login              user    effective_user 
#>          "x86-64"           "sinhn"           "sinhn"           "sinhn"

setwd("Z:/Documents/Professional/SO")
list.files(path = "Sample", recursive = "TRUE")
#> [1] "Folder_C/2020-09-19_18-14.png" "FolderA/2020-09-19_18-14.png" 
#> [3] "FolderB_????"

list.dirs(path = "Sample")
#> [1] "Sample"          "Sample/Folder_C" "Sample/FolderA"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.